# Is it possible to create tmpfs inside lvm puppet module?

Tags: lvm, ramdisk, puppet, tmpfs

we have autoprovisioning of linux machines (using trusty and xenial) and we are using puppet for it.
We are using LVM in [puppetlabs/lvm](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/lvm) and specifying it in hiera.
Example:

```
lvm::volume_groups:
  group1:
    physical_volumes:
      - /dev/sdc
    logical_volumes:
      test:
        mountpath: /var/lib/test
        mountpath_require: true
  group2:
    physical_volumes:
      - /dev/sdb
    logical_volumes:
      data:
        mountpath: /mnt/data
        mountpath_require: true
```

This config in hiera works. Now, I would like to change group1 not to mount physical device, but to use tmpfs instead. I tried

```
  group1:
    physical_volumes:
      - none
    logical_volumes:
      test:
        mountpath: /var/lib/test
        mountpath_require: true
        fs_type: tmpfs
        options: size=1024M
```

But no luck with error message:

```
Parameter name failed on Physical_volume[none]: Physical Volume names must be fully qualified at /etc/puppet/modules/lvm/manifests/volume_group.pp:17
```

Any advice is appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: I know little about puppet, but a good deal about LVM, and I do know that tmpfs is intended to be backed by RAM, not a physical block device (like disk or logical volume(LV)). So you either need a "real" file system (like ext4) on top of LV or use different module to create a tmpfs.